# C Programming - can't close if loop properly

Tags: c

I'm doing a cyber forensics course and part of the course is reverse engineering. They expected us to know C. Oops. I've been coding in C for a grand total of about 16 hours now.

The assignment is to make a student grade calculator. I've done that. My problem is that I'm supposed to end the loop ONLY if the name UNKNOWN is entered as the student's name. I can do it with the character 'q', but not with a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  float grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4; //defining variables//
  char name[32]; //defining variables//

  //This section introduces the quiz calculator and asks for the student's name//
  printf("Welcome to the Student Quiz Calculator Program\n");

  while (1) { //While loop set to always true so it repeats//
    printf("Enter a student name. Enter 'q' to quit: \n"); //Asking for user input//
    scanf("%s", &name); //Take input and assign it as 'name'//

    if (*name == 'q') { //If name matches 'q' terminate program//
      printf("Thanks for using the calculator. Bye!\n");
      break;

    } else {
    printf("Enter quiz grade 1: "); //Asking for user input//
    scanf("%f", &grade1);
    printf("Enter quiz grade 2: "); //Asking for user input//
    scanf("%f", &grade2);
    printf("Enter quiz grade 3: "); //Asking for user input//
    scanf("%f", &grade3);
    printf("Enter quiz grade 4: "); //Asking for user input//
    scanf("%f", &grade4);

    float average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4) / 4; //Performing calculations//
    printf("%s, with grades of %.0f, %.0f, %.0f, and %.0f, your quiz average is %0.2f!\n", name, grade1, grade2, grade3, grade4, average);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code as text. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/68587)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `*name` is equivalent to `name[0]`.  That's why your check for `'q'` works, because you are able to correctly check if the first character in the `name` array is the character `q`.

If you want to see if `name` is equal to some string, you want to use [`strcmp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html):

```
if(strcmp(name, "UNKNOWN") == 0) {
    printf("Thanks for using the calculator. Bye!\n");
    break;
}
```

Comment: it won't let me upvote because I'm new, but thanks so much for the help. I've been stuck on this for two days. I had no idea strcmp was a thing.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Comment: would you mind sending me an email? dejjen@yahoo.com Couldn't find another way to contact you.